# How to make UITableViewCell resizable with two vertical UILabels inside

Tags: ios, swift

I think I am doing everything correctly, but my table view cell doesn't get resized, so my label gets truncated.

Here is my setup inside the cell:

```
                20 (1000)
                   |
                   |
  20 (1000) ---- Title ---- 20 (1000)
                   |
                   |
                20 (1000)
                   |
                   |
  20 (1000) ---- Quote ---- 20 (1000)
                   |
                   |
               >= 20 (1000)
```

Title:

```
Content Hugging Priority: H 251, V 251  
Content Compression Resistance Priority: H 750, V 750
```

Quote:

```
Content Hugging Priority: H 251, V 251  
Content Compression Resistance Priority: H 750, V 750
```

I also have this set inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

And finally, both Title and Quote labels have `numberOfLines` set to 0.

Is there anything I am missing ? The Quote label always gets truncated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the **estimatedRowHeight = 250** and tableView **rowHeight** as `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

**Vertical Constraints for top label :**

> Top = 20
>   Height >= 20
>   Bottom = 20
>   No. of lines = 0
>   lineBreak = wordWrap

**Vertical Constraints of bottom label :**

> Height >= 20
>   Bottom = 20 (**Priority = Low**)
>   No. of lines = 0
>   lineBreak = wordWrap

**Screenshots :**

**1. Top label word wrap (Same for lower label) :**

[image]

**2. Top label constraints :**

[image]

**3. Bottom label constraints :**

[image]

**4. Bottom label bottom space priority :**

[image]

**5. Output on simulator :**

[image]

[**Sample project**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/leyxwngmh4j3oxw/Test.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Doesn't work. Bottom labels always disapears if bottom constraint is <= 10. I tried with greater than 10 , but the labels is bigger, but still gets truncated

Comment: Ok, got the solution. Posting in 2 minutes.

Comment: No need to call `layoutIfNeeded()` in the table's delegate if it's done properly.

Comment: @slickdaddy : Thanks !! Updated.

Comment: The only thing changed is that now the second labels is clipped, not truncated anymore.

Comment: I have shared code at the end of my answer. You can have a look at that.

Comment: Thanks, I am currently make it again from scratch to see if it's anything different.

Comment: Sure. Not a problem.

Comment: So I did a test and it works, without setting the height constraints. Now I am confused why it would not work in my project ......

Comment: Without setting the constraints, it won't work. I would suggest you to recreate the tableCell xib and set constraints one by one. The reason is - sometimes it happens that we keep on undoing or redoing our changes and forget to keep track of the stable point. This would save your time.

Comment: I did the exact constraints I posted in the question, but I follow your advice for bottom constraint to have lower priority. `thats it.

Comment: It worked for the test project made from scratch, but not for my current project...something its wrong with it, still trying to figure out why.

Comment: Like I said, recreate the xib. That would save your time.

Comment: Yep, I found the mistake.....I am using a custom label and not UILabel (I forgot) , apparently it doesn;t work with my custom label just plain UILabel. Thanks, for the help. I will accept this asa the answer.

Comment: Good to hear. Good luck ahead !!

Answer (score 0):

1- in `estimatedRowHeight` put a number that currently address cell height in xib

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 250 
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

2- In cellForRow before return cell put

```
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

see demo here [cellSize](http://www.mediafire.com/file/ow6vxbm12k4lcra/cellSize.rar)

Comment: Same issue. No change...Something seems wrong, I am pretty sure it should work

Comment: change bottom constraint to = instead of >=

Comment: Then I get errors to set vertical hugging priority for both labels . Not sure what values should I put.

Comment: make any of them 1000

Comment: Same. It's still truncated :/

Comment: I am looking at it, but I don't understand,....there are no constraints for the labels ?

Comment: look at mainTableviewcell.xib

Comment: I don't know, it's not working for me, I am doing the same thing.

Comment: you played a lot with resistance hugging copy the cell xib and work with it

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this trick in an answer, but couldn't find the link right now, so I'm going to post my modified version here.

Basically you're forcing the cell to layout to a maximal bound, and calculate the heights required for the labels (after setting the texts).

**In cellForRowAtIndex:**

```
cell.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: 99999)
cell.contentView.bounds = cell.bounds;
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Another thing that can be tried *-after the forced layout in the upper part-*:

```
cell.titleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = cell.titleLabel.frame.width
cell.quoteLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = cell.quoteLabel.frame.width
```

Or you may also calculate it from the width of the `tableView` since the leading space and the trailing space is defined.

Hope this helps.